# Not able to render axios's response with map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing an issue rendering axios get response response in my react component.
I can see that my get request is successfull and that data is retrieved from my backend however when rendering I get this error :

```
TypeError: startup.map is not a function
CardList
C:/personalworkspace/unicorn/front/src/components/CardList.js:30
  27 | 
  28 |  return (
  29 |    <div className="card list">
> 30 |      <Grid container spacing={4}>
     | ^  31 |        {startup.map((startups) => (
  32 |          <Grid key={startups.id} item xs={4}>
  33 |            <Link to={{ pathname: `product/${startups.id}` }}>
```

Here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import CardComponent from './CardComponent';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import StartUpService from './../Services/StartUpService';

const CardList = () => {
  const [startup, setstartups] = useState([]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveTutorials();
  }, []);

  const retrieveTutorials = () => {
    StartUpService.getAll()
      .then((response) => {
        const myData = response.data;
        setstartups(myData);
        console.log(myData);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="card list">
      <Grid container spacing={4}>
        {startup.map((startups) => (
          <Grid key={startups.id} item xs={4}>
            <Link to={{ pathname: `product/${startups.id}` }}>
              <CardComponent
                className="cards"
                key={startups.id}
                id={startups.id}
                image={startups.image}
                header={startups.header}
                title={startups.title}
                category={startups.category}
                summary={startups.summary}
              />
            </Link>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardList;
```

I am not sure what's wrong with my map function?

Here is first object of my API response :

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"header":"First Start Up Header","title":"Title for 
Startup 1","category":"First Start Up Category","description":"First 
Start Up description","tags":

["FINTECH"],"card_image":"http://localhost:8000/media/card_images/card1.jpg","logo_image":"http://localhost:8000/media/logo_images/1.png"},
```

Comment: The error suggests that `startup` isn't an array.  So what is it?  What did `console.log(myData);` reveal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with map. `startup` isn't an array (or other type supporting .map).  `console.log` the api response and you'll see what it really is.

You're code is probably fine the API is just returning data in a format other than what you expect.

Comment: Thanks have added the response!

Comment: @ziwdig44bugs can you console.log startups inside render and show us what it logs? This API response seems reasonable.

Comment: it's showing : [object Object]

Comment: You're first guess seems correct the problem is with my dat cause react error is pointing to that line but not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: That implies you stringified an object somewhere. `({some: 'obj'}).toString()`. Does `StartUpService.getAll()` return a JSON object or a string that you need to JSON.parse? Try logging that API response and make sure it's an actual JS object NOT a string that could be parsed into an object.

Comment: Thanks indeed I adde the then part to my get all, it works now  ! thanks                           const getAll = () => {  return http.get('/startups/').then((response) => response.data);
};